# A solution to restart angular project cli automatically with any modification to proxy.conf.json?

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-cli, restart, file-watcher

I'm asking for some help, we have prox.conf.json which contains our different envs, and in many cases, you need to change the target server and need to restart our angular projectAny tricks on how to prevent restarting and when we change the proxy file, angular-project will restart automatically?

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  '/api': {
    target: target.SCRUMBLE, // adapt to a local minikube or a remote demo env
    secure: false,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api': '',
    },
    logLevel: "debug"
  },
```

Comment: you could look for a combination with `nodemon`, this link doesn't give the direct answer but should give you the idea: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/440

Comment: Thanks for your comment! but it's talking about webpack-dev-server

Answer (score 2):

You could run this command: `npx nodemon -w ./src/proxy.conf.json --exec 'ng serve'`
The command is self explained: nodemon with -w option + the path to the file and in combination with ng serve

The result will look something like this:[image: result-img]

And to add to package.json so that you could run it as a command as you want. I just replace the original `start` with the new command and it works.

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npx nodemon -w ./src/proxy.conf.json --exec 'ng serve'",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```

Please also notice that I'm using Ubuntu. If you're using other operating systems and it doesn't run, check for the "forward slash issue" or "how to run nodemon with -w" in those OS

Comment: Thanks it's helpful! we can add it to package.json?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need also fo figure out a solution with environment.ts 
export const environment = {
production: false,
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
// this variable is used in the keycloak-init.ts in case it is set to overwrite the keycloak url
keycloakClusterUrl: 'your_team_cluster_ip_address',
};

keycloakClusterUrl needs to be changed, so I want to start the project with dynamic argument (cluster_url) any idea?

Answer (score 1):

u can serve ur projet  evrey time that way by passing the clusterUrl as argument :

```
ng serve --configuration=environment.ts --cluster_url=your_team_cluster_ip_address
```

and then in the environment file u can retrieve the argument and to keycloakClusterUrl

```
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
const clusterUrlArg = args.find(arg => arg.startsWith('--cluster_url'));
const clusterUrl = clusterUrlArg ? clusterUrlArg.split('=')[1] : 
'default_url';

export const environment = {
production: false,
baseUrl: 'localhost:4200',
keycloakClusterUrl: clusterUrl
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks good but when I tried it I got Error: Unknown argument: cluster_url

Comment: can u try this one in changing package.json  by runing npm run serve-custom
"scripts":{
 "serve-custom": "ng serve --configuration=environment.ts --cluster_url=your_team_cluster_ip_address"
}

Comment: Th main problem is that ng serve does not accept any unknown arguments

Answer (score 0):

by changing the actual script by this one and runing npm start i think it will work the right way

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "nodemon -w src/proxy.config.json --exec ng serve --proxy-config src/proxy.config.json",
  "build": "ng build",
  "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
  "test": "ng test"
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need also fo figure out a solution with environment.ts 
export const environment = {
production: false,
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
// this variable is used in the keycloak-init.ts in case it is set to overwrite the keycloak url
keycloakClusterUrl: 'your_team_cluster_ip_address',
};

keycloakClusterUrl needs to be changed, so I want to start the project with dynamic argument (cluster_url) any idea?

Comment: @RebaiAhmed i passed a new answer i hope that i will help u